# how to use OL3 vector tiles with a custom map projection

Tags: openlayers-3

We have the following minimal example of using vector tiles.

We have not been able to make this work if we change the map projection to something other than `http://epsg.io/3857`. Is there any way to tell the VectorTile layer or source that it should work on other map projections?

What we experience is that when we change it, it starting to request tiles in the wrong location -looks like the tilegrid is using the new mapprojection to requests tiles instead of the `http://epsg.io/3857` layout that different tools produces.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>OSM Vector Tiles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.16.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.16.0/build/ol-debug.js"></script>
    <style>
        .map {
            background: #f8f4f0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
        var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON({ defaultDataProjection : new ol.proj.Projection({
            code: '',
            units: ol.proj.Units.TILE_PIXELS
        })});

        var tileGrid = ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
            maxZoom: 22
        });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [

                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
                    zIndex: 1
                }),

                new ol.layer.VectorTile({
                    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
                        format: format,
                        tileGrid: tileGrid,
                        tilePixelRatio: 16,
                        url: ...
                    }),
                    renderMode: 'vector',
                    style: [ 
                        new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#33ccff',
            width: 2
          }),
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 2,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: 'red'
            })
          })
        }) 
        ]
                })



            ],
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
                //center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([9.1645879, 55.7383757]), // Billund
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([12.1272493, 55.590296]), // Roskilde

                maxZoom: 22,
                zoom: 12
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to render vector tile layers in a different projection than the one the tiles were created for.